# What does "korobchil" mean?

Tags: лексикон

What does "korobchil" mean?

From this song: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfLeHdTDhUg

Answer (score 5):

> Чичен молодой в озере купался,
>
> Русску девку коробчил, без штанов остался.

That is a verb from a Cossack dialect, `коробчить / карабчить`, it means "to steal; to deceive". There's another possible explanation, the word can be `коропчить` derived from `короп` (carp), then it means "to fish, to catch carp", this fits the song in a better way, the young Chechen used his trousers as a fishing net and lost them.

Comment: I still don't get it.

Comment: @maxim - This is a mocking Cossack song about Chechens. That stanza is about a young Chechen who was bathing in a river and tried to  catch a Russian girl, but lost his trousers instead.

Comment: @maxim Also `остаться без штанов` (`to lose trousers`) is usually used in meaning "to lose all what you have", "to become poor".